# Swift create function closure with shortened dollar sign syntax support

Tags: swift, generics, closures

I've added this extension to Array

```
extension Array {
    func each(call: (element: Element, idx: Int) -> ()) {
        for (idx, element) in enumerate(self) {
            call(element: element, idx: idx)
        }
    }
}
```

It's basically a shortcut to `for in enumerate`. To use it I'd call something like this

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].each { element, idx in 
    print(element)
    return
}
```

This would print `1234` which works, but I'd rather it not require that `return`. When tried in a playground without the return it prints "0 elements" 4 times rather than printing the value.

My goal with the extension is to make it work like the map function, which is really short and easy to apply a function to an array, but in this case call a function on each element without mutating the original.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].map { $0 * 2 } //Converts the array to [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Each can be accomplished by calling

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].each { print($0); return }
```

This works, but rather than returning the element with `$0` it returns a tuple with `(element, idx)`. I could use this pretty easily by using `$0.0` for the element and `$0.1` for the index, but this feels too clunky. I'd prefer to just use `$0` for the element and `$1` for the index with the shortened syntax. I'd also like to prevent that return from being necessary.

So in summary, I'd like to clean up my closure with the shortened `$` syntax by making `$0` the first argument returned and `$1` the second element, and I'd like to make the `return` unnecessary when calling the function with something like `println`.

Comment: Swift 2 has `forEach` :)

Comment: Ah, good to know. I may end up migrating to swift 2 then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift 2.0 already have this expression built in, but if you want to write it yourself, it's as simple as

```
extension CollectionType {    
    func each(@noescape expression: (Self.Generator.Element, int) -> ()) {
        for item in self {
            expression(item)
        }
    }
}
```

And with the index:

```
extension CollectionType {    
    func each(@noescape expression: (Self.Generator.Element, Int) -> ()) {
        for (i, item) in self.enumerate() {
            expression(item, i)
        }
    }
}
```

By extending `CollectionType` this works on both `Array` and other collections, such as `Set`.

Comment: While this works, it doesn't return the index in the array as '$1' along with the object ($0) which is what I was looking for

Comment: Sure, which is just adding it to the expressive. I updated the answer to include it.